# Is it possible to insert multiple child records using the entity framework?

Tags: c#, frameworks, ado.net, entity

Using entity framework.  Is it possible to insert multiple child records.  At the moment I am iterating through a list and adding to entity object, but only one/the last object is saved to the database.  Should I just create a sproc, or is this possible with EF?
e.g.

```
            //dc = datacontext
            var fileList = Session["FileNames"];
            string[] sA = fileList.ToString().Split('|');
            for (int i = 0; i < sA.Count(); i++)
            {                  
                wcc.ID = id; //which has been supplied through a previous 
          //dc.SaveChanges
                wcc.FileName = sA[i];
                dc.AddTotbObject(wcc);                   
            }
            dc.SaveChanges();
            dc.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're only ever adding a single instance. You'll need to do something along these lines within your loop:

```
wcc = new tbObject();
wcc.ID = id;
wcc.FileName = sA[i];
dc.AddTotbObject(wcc);
```